# ASP.NET MVC 4 bundles are not working under mono v3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mono

WebOptimization framewooks seems to not works correctly under mono in release mode

[image: WebOptimization framewooks seems to not work correctly under mono in release mode]

However it works fine if i set debug="true" option in web. config

I tried different things found over internet to fix this issue on IIS like setting module:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="BundleModule" />
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

Seems routes are not registered properly.
Please advise.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found solution myself:

> Also ensure you delete Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll as Mono has its own
>   implementation of this assembly (Microsoft's implementation is dependent on
>   IIS).

After i deleted that file from BIN directory - everyting is working fine. Thank you MONO developer team. Answer was found here [mono mail archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-list@lists.ximian.com/msg36327.html)

Hope this will help somebody!